# Why do navy-blue blocks of glass (sometimes) brighten into cyan, or orange into yellow?

Tags: optics, visible-light, glass

I'm learning how to illustrate transparent mediums realistically. Here are two examples illuminated with white light. I've noticed this doesn't occur with red or green, which stay their own colour. I also notice that cyan is a lower frequency than blue, but yellow is higher than orange.

EDIT: To be clear, I mean the hue (wavelength), not the luminosity (amplitude). The red lines indicate the hue change here:
[image: Example]

Comment: This does not appear to be a question about physics. It seems more like a question about [_photography_](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) or possibly about [_computer graphics_](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Such hue shift can be a result of blown highlights, or even simply the tone curve applied by the camera of the photographer to the linear RGB values. You should always check the linear raw images to judge whether there's some physical effect that affects colors. Cooked images like e.g. JPEG too often contain nonlinearly processed colors.

Comment: IDK if this is completely relevant, but painters have been highlighting green and yellow with mixtures of white, red with orange or peach, orange with pale yellow, and blue with pale cyan, for about five hundred years, to create the illusion of light. Something to do with how the eye processes color and brightness in real life.

Comment: @SolomonSlow A question about light wavelengths being adjusted by a matter medium definitely belongs in physics, regardless of my purpose in asking.

Comment: It's not a question of wavelengths being shifted. You're comparing pixels in digital images. Hues in a photograph are not the same thing as wavelengths of light in the scene that was photographed.

Comment: @SolomonSlow No - digital hue corresponds to wavelength, and digital luminosity corresponds to frequency. This common, everyday physical phenomenon is obviously not digital artifacting and occurs every time someone sees the yellows in a Coke bottle lifted to the sun. You may want to invest in some eyes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complex question. Here are the complexities:

First, "white light" can be either a uniform mix of all possible wavelengths or a carefully chosen mix of red, green and blue light that your eye *interprets* as "white".

Second, colored glass can contain either one chemical substance that absorbs and blocks out one wavelength of light or a mixture of different chemicals that absorb and block out several different wavelengths of light. Playing with the proportions of those chemicals will produce a range of different colors.

For these reasons, the human eye plus a random source of "white" light make a poor combination for doing spectroscopy. I recommend you get a spectrum of your light source and a spectrum of the light that passes through the blocks and compare the two.

Cheap diffraction spectrographs made of pieces sliced off a compact disc mounted in a cardboard housing will suffice. Instructions for how to build them are on the Interwebs and this is a fun project for students to do. You can also find diffraction gratings that attach to a cell phone; running an app on the phone will turn the phone into a very cool spectrometer which allows you to share spectra by messaging!

Comment: done! thanks- NN